# how to get the content which is pasted using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the content which is pasted(by right clicking mouse and then paste not the keyboard ctrl + v paste option) using paste event in jquery. Please someone help  me solving this.

```
       <div class="note"></div>
       <textarea id="textarea" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>

        <script>

        $(function(){
            $("#textarea").on("keyup",function(){
                $(".note").html($(this).val());
            });
        });

        //keyup event works fine normally. But I want the paste event to do the same job.

        $(function(){
            $("#textarea").on("paste",function(){
                $(".note").html($(this).val());
            });
        });

       </script>
```

Comment: i am unable to get the content which i am pasting using $(this).val()

Comment: did you try `change` event of the textbox?

Comment: But the doesnt change once we paste.. we need to click  outside to run it..even the paste event is not working on first paste . it working when we paste second time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#textarea").on('keyup paste', function(e) {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function(){
        alert(e.target.value);
    }, 200));
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M9MrE/)

note: changed bind to on which is preferable.

Comment: We are adding a delay in the event so it only fire once. For example if you want to paste something you press `ctrl` a keyup event will occur. That is why you were seeing blank response when you first time paste. In this case there is a slight delay added so it will not fire the keyup event if you do `ctrl` but will fire the keyup event in case of `ctrl+V`. obviously if you are not holding the `ctrl` key for a long time than the delay time

Comment: Thanks for the explaination :)

Comment: Why is the timeout set to 200? Why not just set it to 1?